# how do we resolve multiple package conflicts in coda

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install OpenCV in Anaconda.
The installation fails due to a conflict of packages.

Below is the list of conflicts:

```
Package lz4 conflicts for:
libarchive -> zstd[version='>=1.3.7,<1.3.8.0a0'] -> lz4
zstd -> lz4
libtiff -> zstd[version='>=1.3.7,<1.3.8.0a0'] -> lz4
blosc -> zstd[version='>=1.3.7,<1.3.8.0a0'] -> lz4

Package pympler conflicts for:
pytest -> attrs[version='>=17.2.0'] -> pympler
spyder -> pympler
attrs -> pympler

Package pycosat conflicts for:
conda-build -> conda[version='>=4.5'] -> pycosat[version='>=0.6.1|>=0.6.3']
anaconda==2019.10 -> pycosat==0.6.3[build='py36hfa6e2cd_0|py27h0c8e037_0|py37hfa6e2cd_0']
conda[version='>=4.8.3'] -> pycosat[version='>=0.6.3']

Package networkx conflicts for:
anaconda==2019.10 -> networkx[version='2.2|2.3',build='py_0|py27_1']
scikit-image -> networkx[version='>=1.8,<2.0|>=1.8|>=2.0']
anaconda==2019.10 -> scikit-image==0.15.0=py36ha925a31_0 -> networkx[version='>=1.8']

Package coverage conflicts for:
pytest astropy -> hypothesis -> coverage
Attrs -> hypothesis -> coverage
```

It would be great if someone can help me resolve these conflicts or help me in installing OpenCV package.
Conda version: 4.8.3
Python version: 3.7.4

Comment: Where are you trying to install it? Is it your base environment?

Comment: Please provide the contents of the environment.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to work with `conda` is to use environments. This allowed separation of packages from one project to another and also minimize any packages conflicts. From your logs I see that a package like `anaconda` is listed meaning you are likely install in your `base` environment. As a rule of thump, never install packages to your base. Always create environments for each of your projects.

This is how I will install opencv:

```sh
#create environment called vision with Python 3.7 and opencv from a channel conda-forge
condo create -n vision -c conda-forge python=3.7 opencv

#activate and use your environment: this should print the version of cv
conda activate vision
python -c "import cv2;print(cv2.__version__)"

#to deactivate this environment 
conda deactivate
```

Every time you are working with opencv, activate this environment and you will have all you need.

You can also add any other packages you need e.g.

```sh
# conda install to environment named vision from channel conda-forge tensorflow
conda install -n vision -c conda-forge tensorflow
```

If you really have to use `pip`, as a last resort, make sure that you are in the environment:

```
pip install PACKAGENOTINCONDA
```

Again, avoid to use `pip` on `base` environment. You can use it on your created environment. See https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment

Answer (score -1):

I tried to install using pip and it worked.
Command:

```
pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: This is not a wise way to fix your problem. `conda` was warning you that some packages were not playing together. Until now, `pip` lacks that future and ignores warnings and install packages anyway. This can cause damage.